# How to create an array of PictureBoxes and use it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I thought "brickn()" will creat an array and "NoOfBrick"  will be the array length and all array will store in it

```
Dim brickWidth as Integer = 0
Dim Brickn() As PictureBox  
dim NoOfBrick as Integer       ' array length

Public Function CreateBrick() As PictureBox
  Dim myBrickn As New PictureBox

  With myBrickn
    .Size = Brick.Size
    .Left = BrickWidth
    .Top = 0
    .Image = Brick.Image
    .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    .BackColor = Color.Black
  End With

  Return myBrickn
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   For i = -75 To Me.Width 
     Brickn(NoOfBrick) = CreateBrick() 'and also how to add array/list here 
     Me.Controls.Add(Brickn(NoOfBrick))
     BrickWidth += 170 'increasing brick.left on every new brick is created 
     i += 170          ' increasing looop count according to brick needed    
     NoOfBrick +=1
  Next
End Sub
```

But this code is throwing error on "Me.Controls.Add(Brickn(NoOfBrick))"
this error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I thought if I will get array of PictureBoxes then I can access control on them for this

```
Private Sub Boll_control_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Boll_control.Tick
  If Ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(brickn(NoOfBrick).Bounds) Then
    Me.Controls.Remove(brickn(NoOfBrick))
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Dim Brickn() As PictureBox
```

To:

```
Dim Brickn As New List(Of PictureBox)
```

Then, when you want to `Add` something to "Brickn", you'd do:

```
Brickn.Add(CreateBrick())
```

You can still access "Brickn" with array syntax, such as:

```
Brickn(NoOfBrick).Bounds
```

The difference is that a List will automatically grow or shrink in size as you add/remove things to it, while an Array has a fixed size (you never actually created the array in your code and gave it a size).

You can do hit testing with something like:

```
Dim hit = Brickn.Where(Function(brick) Ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(brick.Bounds))
For Each brick As PictureBox In hit
    Me.Controls.Remove(brick)
    Brickn.Remove(brick)
Next
```

Comment: If Ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(brickn(NoOfBrick).Bounds) Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(brickn(NoOfBrick))
        End If      
this code is not working :(  u said it will work

Comment: Define "not working". What is the value of `NoOfBrick`? How many things are in the List? The first thing in the List is at Index 0 (ZERO), not one, so you have to account for that.

Comment: See edited code at the bottom for an alternate way to do hit testing.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.' 

throwing this error

Comment: With the edited code I just posted at the bottom, or with your attempt at using the `List(Of PictureBox)` change from the original post?

Comment: Ok ok i found it thanks a lotttt its now working i just removed "brickn.remove(brick) " then code started working this code was new for me btwlearnd new things thanks ;)